# Instantiate a concrete class based on generic parameter c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

Well, I tried to wrap my mind around this with no luck; can't find a better solution so I would gladly use some help/ideas.

Basically, I have a generic method which receives a businessobject as generic parameter and it should instantiate a EntityFramework entity and return it. There is a naming convention between the businessobject name and the entity framework name (i.e. if the BO is named 'UsersBo', then the EF entity is named 'Users') and that convention is enforced everywhere.

My code looks like this:

```
public dynamic CreateEntity<T>()
{
    switch (typeof(T).Name)
    {
        case "UsersBo":
           return new Users();
        case "RolesBo":
           return new Roles();
        case "AppObjectsBo":
           return new AppObjects();
        default:
           break;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Given the fact the BO and EF entity are located in different DLLs (BLL.dll vs DAL.dll), how the heck do I instantiate it without that ugly switch command? Tried with Activator.CreateInstance and it gave me errors regarding "fully qualified name"
2. Is there any way to *NOT* use Dynamic objects? Right now I'm using dynamic becase I can't know which concrete class will be instantiated.

Thank you

================================
Later edit:

Here's the actual code:

```
public T GetById(Guid id)
        {
            T entityBo = new T();
            var entity = new EntityFactory().CreateEntity<T>();
            var repository = new EntityFactory().CreateRepository<T>();
            try
            {
                entity = repository.GetById(id);
                if (entity != null)
                {
                    Mapper.Map(entity, entityBo);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                entityBo = default(T);
                throw ex.GetBaseException();
            }
            return entityBo;
        }
```

=====================
I have a generic service class which works with business objects. Of course, these must be mapped to the corresponding EF objects.

If I'm calling the above method using UsersBo as T, the code will become:

```
public UsersBo GetById(Guid id)
        {
            UsersBo entityBo = new UsersBo(); // no problem here
            var entity = new EntityFactory().CreateEntity<T>(); // That's the problem line: T is UsersBo, but I need a new Users (EF entity) in order to do the mapping later
            var repository = new EntityFactory().CreateRepository<T>();
            try
            {
                entity = repository.GetById(id); // this one returns the EF entity
                if (entity != null)
                {
                    Mapper.Map(entity, entityBo);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                entityBo = default(T);
                throw ex.GetBaseException();
            }
            return entityBo;
        }
```

Hopefully now makes more sense. I am open to any suggestions, maybe I'm completely off and there's a better way.

Thank you guys.

=============

Slept over it. Top-notch answers, already changed the code and works like a charm. Thank you, guys, you were extremely helpful.

Comment: Why not create an overload of `CreateEntity` for each specific type instead of using a generic? `public Users CreateEntity(UsersBo usersbo){ return new Users(); };` etc.

Comment: Why cant you use new T() and put a constraint on the method where T : new()?

Comment: @MattWilko: The application will grow pretty big - I expect it to have like 200+ concrete classes. In my oppinion, the ideal approach would be to find a way to instantiate the EF entity just based on name, instead getting back to code whenever a new entity is added in DB. The goal is to write as less code as possible.

Comment: @Botonomous: if I correctly understood your answer, the instantiated entity will be of the same type as the received parameter. In this particular case, the parameter is a class, the return type is a different class and there's no inheritance between them.

Comment: What is the benefit of this convention? At some point you have to 1) create the correct EF type, 2) map values of the BLL type to the EF type and then 3) do something with the updated EF type like persist it to the store. How do you foresee this creation helping in that process (maybe its a part of a large picture)?

Comment: @Igor: I added more code, hopefully it will make more sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this but I still do not like the overall design because you are forgoing type safety with the keyword `dynamic`. It would be better to use the passed in type constraint to get back the exact type you want to use in the calling code.

```
// personally i would change dynamic to object
// calling code could always cast to dynamic if it needed to
public dynamic CreateEntity<T>()
{
    var bllName = typeof(T).Name;
    var efName = bllName.Substring(0, bllName.Length - 2); // removes "Bo"

    var className = string.Concat("Namespace.", efName, ", EfAssembly.dll");
    var efType = Type.GetType(className);
    return efType != null ? Activator.CreateInstance(efType) : null;
}
```

---

This (see code below) would be my preference, here `T` would be the actual EF entity that you want to work with in the calling code and is not related at all to your BLL type. Alternatively you could enrich your BLL types to return the correct EF types but the negative on that is SoC as you would be breaking the loose coupling rule.

```
public T CreateEntity<T>() where T : class, new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

---

Based on your latest edit I refined your code with how you could approach this.

```
public T GetById<T>(Guid id) where T : new()
{
    T entityBo = new T();

    // this should not be needed, you do not use the results anywhere unless your EF type provides for some defaults at the BLL layer but it would be better to include those defaults in the BLL types constructor instead
    // var entity = new EntityFactory().CreateEntity<T>(); // That's the problem line: T is UsersBo, but I need a new Users (EF entity) in order to do the mapping later

    // this is the line where you need to implement the translation to get the correct repository type
    var repository = new EntityFactory().CreateRepository<T>();
    try
    {
        // get your object from your repository or if it returns null then you will end up just returning the default bll instance which is OK
        var entity = repository.GetById(id);
        if (entity != null)
        {
            // map what was returned
            Mapper.Map(entity, entityBo);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // no need for this, it adds nothing
        // entityBo = default(T);

        // do not do this
        // throw ex.GetBaseException();

        // this is better, it preserves the stack trace and all exception details
        throw;
    }
    return entityBo;
}
```

Comment: I don't like this, because the method returns dynamic. I hate dynamics! :-) You can cast the result of Activator.CreateInstance(efType) to T type. See my answer.

Comment: @IgorDamiani - I think you are missing the OPs point. `T` represents the BLL type but based on T the OP wants to return the corresponding EF type so you can not cast that newly created type back to T unless there is inheritance (which is not mentioned in the post above). The only commonality is the naming convention.

Comment: maybe you can simply return object instead of dynamic? So the client code can call GetType to get the real type.

Comment: @IgorDamiani - I agree, the calling code could always cast the result to `dynamic` if it needed to.  Added a note in the code but left it as is as that is what the OP wanted.

Comment: @Igor: indeed, there's no inheritance involved anywhere.

Comment: I'm just wondering how the rest of the world does the 3-tier design. I bet I am missing something obvious, but I'd be damned if I know what :)

Comment: @GrigoreDolghin - there are libraries available like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/) which can be used to map between 2 types that share similar properties. This makes it easy to populate an EF type from a BLL type if they share common state and naming conventions. This reduces the amount of repetitive code you need to write to translate state back and forth between similar types.

Comment: @GrigoreDolghin - alternatively if an EF model does not differ at all from the BLL/presentation model it is also acceptable to pass the EF model all the way through and back again. This could be the case with some (but not all) models.

Comment: @GrigoreDolghin - I updated my answer based on your edit.

Comment: @Igor: thank you SO much. Very very helpful indeed. Thanks again.

Comment: I agree with @Igor 's refactor for `T GetById<T>`

Answer (score 4):

Activator.CreateInstance is correct, but you need to specify the fully qualified name of the class, in your case something like this:

```
string className = T.GetType().Name.Replace("Bo", string.Empty);
var fullClassName = string.Concat("Namespace.", className, ",BLL.dll");
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance("BLL.dll", fullClassName);
return obj;
```

The fully qualified name of a class contains the full path of namespaces. In the CreateInstance method you need to specify also the DLL name where the class is defined. Please replace "Namespace." with the actual namespace.

Comment: Well that can't work. T is not the type returned by the `CreateInstance`, it's the type used to get the name. But the main idea is here.

Comment: Hey @romain-aga, you are right! :-) Maybe he can remove "Bo" in this way: T.GetType().Name.Replace("Bo", string.Empty).

Comment: you should edit your answer with this, you have the half of the work, here. It can still help ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help. In this case, return obj will be a different type every time; how does the method signature looks like?

public ??? CreateEntity<T>

What gets in place of question marks? I used dynamic becase of this but I don't really like it

Comment: The signature of the method can be public object CreateEntity<T>(). But I prefer the solution offered by the other Igor! :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could creating a mapper between your business object and your entity objects.

```
[TestClass]
public class EFMappingTest {
    [TestMethod]
    public void MappperTest() {
        EntityFactory.Map<UsersBo, Users>();
        EntityFactory.Map<RolesBo, Roles>();
        EntityFactory.Map<AppObjectsBo, AppObjects>();

        var factory = new EntityFactory();

        var entity = factory.CreateEntity<UsersBo>();

        Assert.IsNotNull(entity);
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(entity, typeof(Users));
    }

    class Users { }
    class UsersBo { }
    class Roles { }
    class RolesBo { }
    class AppObjects { }
    class AppObjectsBo { }

    public class EntityFactory {
        static IDictionary<Type, Type> mappings = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();

        public static void Map<TBusinessObject, TEntity>() where TEntity : class, new() {
            Map(typeof(TBusinessObject), typeof(TEntity));
        }

        public static void Map(Type sourceType, Type targetType) {
            mappings[sourceType] = targetType;
        }

        public object CreateEntity<T>() {
            Type entityType = null;
            return mappings.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out entityType)
                ? Activator.CreateInstance(entityType)
                : null;
        }

        public TEntity CreateEntity<TEntity>(object businessObject) where TEntity : class {
            if (businessObject == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("businessObject");
            Type businessObjectType = businessObject.GetType();
            Type entityType = null;
            return mappings.TryGetValue(businessObjectType, out entityType)
                ? (TEntity)Activator.CreateInstance(entityType)
                : null;
        }
    }
}
```

Given your concern about the number of mapping to make. You said you have a convention. You can automate the mappings by enumerating your business objects and searching for entities that match your convention and then map them.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: one other solution added**

I have 3 solutions to propose, but it works only if you have interfaces for both your entities and your model objetcs:

### Something like @Igor Damiani said:

```
TInterface Instantiate<TEntity, TInterface>()
        where TEntity : class, TInterface
        where TInterface : class
{
    return (TInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("Namespace" + typeof(TEntity).FullName.Replace("Bo", "")));
}
```

Usage: `IEntity instance = Instantiate<EntityType, IEntity>();`

### The dictionary method:

```
Dictionary<Type, Type> _types = new Dictionary<Type, Type>
{
    { typeof(IEntityA), typeof(ModelA) },
    { typeof(IEntityB), typeof(ModelB) }
};

TInterface Instantiate<TInterface>()
        where TInterface : class
{
    return (TInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(_types[typeof(TInterface)].FullName.Replace("1", "2")));
}
```

Usage: `IEntity instance = Instantiate<IEntity>();`

### The third

would be an hybrid between the @Igor Damiani, @Nkosi's solutions to fill the dictionary and call the `Activator.CreateInstance` method.

But all of this, works only if you have interface.

---

### Edit: The T4 solutions

Entity Framework Edmx is a T4 template.
Then you can edit it to generate your old class (if you use the assembly of your models in the same assembly as the edmx).

Or you can generate the dictionary with the edmx.

(Whatever, creating the links between your entities and your models, can become really easy thanks to the edmx)

Comment: thank you very much for you help, it's very interesting. I don't have interfaces, but it's never too late. I'm going to look into it. Thanks again.